# Variance vs mean distance to centroid

Tags: clustering, variance

I am confused, and I am about to ask a really dumb question.

I am evaluating a (kind of) clustering model, and I want to analyse how "spread out" the samples in each cluster are.
My intuition was to take the **mean Euclidean distance to the assigned cluster centroid** of all samples of the same cluser.
My question now is, how is this different from variance? According to Wikipedia:

> Informally, it measures how far a set of (random) numbers are spread out from their average value.

However, when I compute the variance, it is not the same as the mean distance to the centroid. Why is that? Which one is the *better* metric here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would recommend looking at is the actual formulae for calculating these. The mean distance to the centroid of a single cluster is just the mean absolute deviation. If this statistic is the mean absolute deviation than variance is the mean squared deviation or the average squared distance between each data point and the mean. This is why they are different, because in the mean distance case each distance is not squared.

This then approaches the deeper question of why variance is used as opposed to something like mean absolute deviation and while there are many reasons for or against each, variance is primarily used for historical reasons. The variances of a series of samples from a population are less spread out than the mean absolute deviation of those samples, and thus variance is more consistent, which seems to be the primary reason it has become the winner over the years. But for any given situation, mean absolute deviation may be a better choice.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! It makes sense now.